# How does Series.Points.Add method triger the redraw of the chart contol?

Tags: .net, charts, series, redraw

When using the Chart control, invoking the `Add` method to add new data point, such as `Series.Points.AddXY()`, will trigger a redraw of the chart control. Now, I am trying to build a chart control by myself. I am wondering; how does it work. Is it using events and delegates or some other way to trigger the redraw?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this by creating your own class that inherits `Collection<T>` and overrides `InsertItem()` and other methods to redraw the chart when the collection is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the Refresh function inside the Series.Points.AddXY() function?

You probably want to be able to turn 'auto refresh' off in case someone wants to add 1,000 points one-by-one....the redrawing would kill performance.